# Setting foreign key in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to make **namecon** of table **"paper"** as a foreign key reference to table **"journal"** to its primary key *jname*. I am getting confused with this view and not finding any tutorial or link which is explaining to set foreign key with this schema of phpMyAdmin. (Is it new or what)
Please someone let me to figure this out.

[image: This is how the relation looks like]

Comment: Hi, What is your need ? how to set the foreign key ?

Comment: I guess the [first search](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Setting+foreign+key+in+phpMyAdmin) should give you solution !

Comment: First create the Auto increment id to paper table.

Comment: atleast google before you post a question

Comment: and the create then create the field paper_id in journal table .Don't set auto increment for that id

Comment: yeah, but don;t you find difference in the way they are appearing (i.e. their schema). In my schema there are two boxes vacant in internal relation.
Then they are asking for the constraint name and column (column is only showing the primary key of current table i.e. paper). How to deal with all these options. Where as the search page which you are giving is simple internal relation and then foreign key relation.

Comment: @Manashvibirla I did and after reading the question properly you will get to know the difference between the solutions on Google and this problem.

Comment: @KarthikKeyan journal table has primary key which is "jname". and paper table has an attribute "namecon". now I want to set this "namecon" as foreing key. I am not getting how this auto Increment thing will solve this problem. Can you elaborate please ?

Comment: Please delete all values from tables, Before you set the foreign key

Comment: There are no values stored in it.

Comment: Click relationship view in the phpmyadmin on table structure

Comment: After doing that only I am getting the schema which I have posted in the picture. Next is what I am unable to do due to lots of boxes emerging into it. And I have described in one of my comments that how this is difference from rest of the schema available on google.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79936/discussion-between-hawkeye-and-karthik-keyan).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While making the foreign key, it is also advisable to mark the index key option available int Structure view of the table.
That will make the primary key thing to visible in the relational view of that particular table which can be used for making foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to create an index on the `namecon` column, click on the Structure tab ("Table structure" sub-heading on newer phpMyAdmin versions), then the `Index` text for the namecon column. You also need an index on the `jname` column in your `journal` table; in most of my databases this is an auto incrementing primary key but all that MySQL requires is that it's an index.

Next, go back to the Relation View (which is a sub-heading of Structure under newer versions). Note that this is in the area for "Foreign key constraints" not "Internal relations." Now you'll be able to select namecon from the "Column" dropdown:

[image: Relations dialog box]

If you want you can give it a name, otherwise MySQL generates one for you.